# Prevent user from changing id before update in WebApps

Tags: java, security, design-patterns, crud

This is a general question.

I have a doubt related to IDs in CRUD operations and other action where an ID has to be sent.

I mean, no matter what technolgy is used, the result will be a html form where the Id will be in an input field inside a form (maybe ofuscated, hidden, but always it is present). Considering this way the user can modify the entityId using firebug (for example) and send the form with a different id, this will allow the user to update or even delete a record that was not the original one requested.

```
<form>
    <input id="entityId" type="hidden"/>
    <input  id="someName" type="button"/>
</form>
```

How I can manage this situation? 
The first solution that I try is make a select by userId and entityId, so I can allow the user to update only his own records, BUT he can still change the id and make changes in another records owned by him.

How I can restrict more the user to make changes only in the record shown by the web application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe from your servlet side, set the current entityid for the user in a session variable and check that they match.

Comment: You need to check that the values submitted are valid and they have permission to modify them

Comment: @AndrewBarber I guess the OP knows this and is asking how

Comment: @ScaryWombat Wombat you are right. the idea is how.
No sure if store it in the session is a good idea, what about if I have a grid with 100 records and I can edit all of them, if I store all the records in the session it could lead to a memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should not write the record id into the web form, but instead, save it in the user's session on the server.

Use

```
request.getSession().setAttribute(name, value);
```

to set it, and

```
request.getSession().getAttribute(name);
```

to read it.

That way, it can't be tampered with.

If instead you need to allow multiple forms (and records) with a single session, you might track them in a set attached to the session.

Comment: It is a general question, what about if the backend is a rest web service?. And if I don't send the user name what can I do if the name is not unique?